# Como gerar um número sequencial em um formulário PHP, sem usar banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, formulário, funções

Hoje no meu formulário, eu tenho o arquivo mail.php onde ler os dados do formulário e envia por e-mail. Esse formulário é um formulário de pedido online, onde os usuários já cadastrados logan e fazem os pedidos. 
Bem, montei tudo com base em pesquisas e estudos na web, não sou um conhecedor da linguagem em php, mas entendo pouquinho.
Hoje eu cheguei a colocas o código (abaixo), para gerar os números aleatórios com a função rand(), para não correr o risco de repetir números eu achei essa formula:

```
<?
$numeros = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$total_num = count($numeros)-1;
$numPedido = $id . $numeros[rand(0,$total_num)] . $numeros[rand(0,$total_num)] . $numeros[rand(0,$total_num)] ;
$gerador = $numPedido;


?>
```

Bem, resolveu, gerar números sem a necessidade de Banco de Dados, mas gostaria de usar sequencial, tem como?
Tem como alguma função, em javascript, sei lá, que possa salvar a informação do número em  arquivo TXT e depois consultar o arquivo para não repetir o número?

Já achei vários tutoriais sobre o uso de BD, mas achei complicado. Já que o formulário de pedido não é salvo em nenhum lugar, ele apenas é enviado por e-mail, só usamos o BD para carregar os dados do usuário e claro, para ele ter acesso ao pedido online.

Esse código que usei coloquei no arquivo mail.php. Assim o número aparece no corpo do e-mail e coloquei para aparecer também no assunto.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos!!

Comment: Onde será usado esse número?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar o banco de dados é a melhor alternativa.

Usar Javascript é impossível, isso roda no lado do cliente, não no servidor, esquece.

O que você pode usar é um alternativa ao banco de dados, se pesquisar por "PHP without DB store data" irá achar soluções semelhantes.

**Ideia:**

Mantenha um arquivo .txt ou .php, exemplo, que simplesmente contenha alguma informação, nesse caso, a informação do último valor inserido.

**Como fazer?**

Há várias maneiras.

**Exemplo:**

### Usando include:

Para salvar a informação use:

```
file_put_contents('contagem.php', '<?php $contagem='.((int)$contagem+1).' ?>');
```

Para pegar a informação use:

```
include('contagem.php');
```

**Resumo:**

O `contagem.php` sempre irá possuir a variável `$contagem` seguinte.

**Aplicação em seu caso:**

Usando a variável `$contagem` e a variável `$gerador` terá isso:

```
<?

// Verifica se contagem.php existe
/* Se for a primeira vez que executa ele não irá existir. */
if( file_exists('contagem.php')){
    // Se existir inclui a variavel que armazena a informação
    include('contagem.php');
}

// Salva o proximo número no contagem.php (apagando a informação anterior e salvando o proximo número).
file_put_contents('contagem.php', '<?php $contagem='.((int)$contagem+1).' ?>');

// Exibe o $gerador que é igual a $contagem.
/* Remova o echo para ocultar obviamente */
echo $gerador = (int)$contagem;

?>
```

No final, cada vez será acrescentado um a $contagem anterior. Dessa forma o primeiro será 0 (devido ao `(int)`) o próximo será 1, depois 2,3,4,5,6...

**Notas:**

> Nota na primeira vez  que executar será mostrado erros de Notice, porque a variável `$contagem` não existe, mesmo assim seu valor será 0 normalmente. Nas próximas vezes existirá o `$contagem`, portanto não haverá o tal erro.

### Veja mais

Se quiser ver mais sobre o `file_put_contents` e o `include` veja no manual em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php e http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php.

Há alternativas de usar o `file_get_contents` em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php ou usando o `fopen`, mas mais complexo, em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php.

Comment: Meu amigo, ajudou e muitoooooo! Muito obrigado pela atenção, mas só uma coisa, tem como esse arquivo contagem.php ser zerado por dia?

Comment: Pode usar uma nova variável com date() dentro dele, e comparar com um externo (no mesmo arquivo que tem o $gerador).

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar aqui! Sou muito cru em PHP, tenho muito que estudar ainda...rs. Mas valeu mesmo meu amigo!